# How can I use multiple Floating Help Dialogue by using 'class' instead of 'id'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to use multiple floating help dialog boxes in a page. I have tried it by using 'display:block' and 'display:none' and used ID in javascript. I cannot use classes since I have multiple of them on the same page and if I use classes then all of them will be displayed/hide at the same time. However, as the number of help items are increasing in the page, I have to go back to the javascript and add more lines  ...

for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#help-icon1").click(function() {
         $('#help-details1').css('display', 'block');
      });

   $("#help-icon2").click(function() {
         $('#help-details2').css('display', 'block');
      });

   $("#help-icon3").click(function() {
         $('#help-details3').css('display', 'block');
      });

});
```

Each of them also have close icons and they should be disappeared if clicked on that close icon or clicked anywhere in the page. That means I have to write javascript functions 3 times for all the different close icons.

I tried to rely on jquery's "next" feature, but since there are many layers (div/p/span) in between the areas where the help icon is places and the help text, it becomes problamatic. Any idea or any better way to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you are looking for, but you can set up all the click handlers in one step, and have each one refer to itself in the handler:

```
jQuery(".help-icon").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: That would toggle the icons but I believe the OP is trying to toggle associated divs, not the icons themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional class names to an element.

A div can be hidden by default, and a new class can be appended to it - to "overrule" the previous style (Hence the name Cascading Style Sheets)

```
<div class="hidden exception"></div>
```

If an element is clicked, you can append a new classname like so:

```
 $('.target').addClass('newclass');
```

more info:
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the jQuery [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function?

**EDIT**: Like the following

```
$(".help-icon").each(function(idx, elm){
    elm.click(function(){
      ...
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not done it using JQuery but what you need is "unobtrusive javascript".

It does get done by using a class. Say you have images you all want highlighted:

```
<img src="pic1.png" onMouseover="this.src='hi_pic1.png';" />
```

so they all have the same behaviour. Give them a class:

```
<img src="pic1.png" class="hi" />
```

Then at load time, on in the script at the end of your page, yahoo-style, you write an initialisation to
- grab every element of the class
- add the event(s) you want
- set the event to use the appropriate data, e.g. by using this and by using systematic names like pic1 -> hi_pic1.

Hope this helps,
Charles

Answer (score 0):

If all of your help icons have the same class you can use jQuery's `each` function to loop through them, retrieve the associated id, replace "icon" with "detail" in the id (so #help-icon3 would become #help-detail3), and then use that to update the panel. Something like:

```
$(".help-icon").each(function() {
    var detailsId = $(this).attr("id").replace("icon", "details");
    $("#" + detailsId).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's just ASSUME that you need to use IDs for some unknown reason.  Here's your answer to combine efforts:

```
$("#help-icon1").add("#help-icon2").add("#help-icon3").click(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Which equates to:

```
$("#help-icon1, #help-icon2, #help-icon3").click(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
});
```

But really, you don't need to use unique IDs like this without some pretty good reasons.